# How can I split a large ISO file?

Tags: windows, iso-image, nero

I have a 6 GB .ISO file (a PC game) that I would  like to split into two 3 GB files so that it would fit into 2 DVDs.

How can I do this? Is there some application or command that can do the job? And after I split it, how do I merge it back together later?

Comment: What kind of disk would it be? Data, DVD-Video, Bootable? etc...

Comment: of course it would be data, unless there's a bootable pc game

Comment: Why don't you just use a dual-layer DVD?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either [rar](http://www.rarlab.com/) to split it into parts, or extract the individual files from the iso with something like  [imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/) and make a new iso at the destination.

Answer (score 9):

if you're on linux you can do:

```
split -b 3G big.iso part
```

to split the `big.iso` into 3GiB parts named `partaa`, `partab` etc.

then use `cat` to put the files back together:

```
cat part* > big.iso
```

See `man split` for more information.

Comment: This will also work on other operating systems if you have UN*X style utilities on your system -- I have these on my Mac (I think they're part of the OS), and also on my Windows PC (courtesy of Git).

Answer (score 6):

You can use a file splitter/joiner utility to achieve this. [**HJSplit**](http://www.freebyte.com/hjsplit/#win32) and [**GSplit**](http://www.gdgsoft.com/gsplit/) are two good options. Both are freeware and very easy to use. HJSplit is a 344 KB file that does not need to be installed. A portable edition of GSplit is also available with no required installation.

Answer (score 4):

There are various File Splitters that work in DOS.  Then use 
COPY /b file1+file2+file_n Originalfile  to reassemble.

Or try http://www.filesplitter.org/

Comment: COPY works like a charm and is perfekt for reassembling

Answer (score 2):

WinRar is quick and easy.